# How to use one $i++ for each loop

Tags: php, foreach

The following code loops thru an images directory and outputs them with div's. I would like to use the images as labels so I can use them as a select.

For this I need unique id's for each input so I did that with the $i++ thing:

```
$i = 1;
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('img/thumbnail') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo "<label for='grid-item-" . $i++ . "'><div class='grid-item' style='background-image: url(img/thumbnail/" . $fileInfo->getFilename() . ");'></div></label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' id='grid-item-" . $i++ . "'>";
}
```

However, with this loop each $i++ gets incremented like so:

label **for** -> 1

input **id** -> 2

label **for** -> 3

input **id** -> 4

But I would like to group them so the label and input's match:

label **for** -> 1

input **id** -> 1

label **for** -> 2

input **id** -> 2

How can I loop this per 2 items?

Comment: ```<input type='checkbox' id='grid-item-" . $i . "'>``` Just use $i the second time without incrementing it

Comment: You're incrementing too many times. Do it at the end of your foreach instead of inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just increment the $i once instead of twice. Try following example:

```
    $i = 1;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('img/thumbnail') as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
        echo "<label for='grid-item-" . $i . "'><div class='grid-item' style='background-image: url(img/thumbnail/" . $fileInfo->getFilename() . ");'></div></label>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='grid-item-" . $i . "'>";
        $i++;
    }
```